# How to find out how many times a max value occurs in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max

I wondered how to solve the following problem in pandas:

I have a dataframe with a number of rows that have different values and would like to find out how often the highest value occurs per row. I have used df2 ['MAX_Value']=df2.max(axis=1) to get the highest value per row.

This is an example of my dataframe:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Col6 MAX_Value 
0      5   6    6    6    3     6
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is expected output? New column filled by `3` ? Or Series with `1` because only one value `6` in `MAX_Value` ?

Comment: Yes it was the expected output I not get how many times (3) each highest value per row occurs!! :-)

Comment: Ok, so need `df2.MAX_value.value_counts()` ?

Comment: No, I used your first suggestion df = df2.assign(MAX_Value = max_val, No = count_max)
print (df) - which works great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with comapring by [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and `sum` per rows:

```
max_val = df2.max(axis=1)
count_max = df2.eq(max_val, axis=0).sum(axis=1)
```

For improve performance is possible use `numpy`:

```
arr = df2.values
max_val = arr.max(axis=1)
count_max = (arr == max_val[:, None]).sum(axis=1)
```

---

```
df = df2.assign(MAX_Value = max_val, No = count_max)
print (df)
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  Col6  MAX_Value  No
0     0     5     6     6     6     3          6   3
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df2.eq(max_val, axis=0))
    Col1   Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5   Col6
0  False  False  True  True  True  False
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your questing correct:

Since you already have column MAX_value, you could just do:

```
df2.MAX_value.value_counts()
```

Let me know if this is what you're looking for! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use a simple groupby :

```
df2.groupby('MAX_Value').Col1.count()
```